# Where are packages installed from Ubuntu terminal stored in windows

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, terminal

I recently downloaded the Ubuntu terminal on windows 10, because a repository I'm experimenting with requires OCaml and opam. I've run into an error and to solve it I need to delete some opam files (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54987110/installing-ocaml-on-windows-10-using-wsl-ubuntu-problems-with-bwrap-bubblewr). The solutions is to delete ~/.opam/config, but I'm unable to find this file on my windows system. I've looked in C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin, but it doesn't seem to have any opam related folders. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you can find these files in the Windows filesystem if you’re using WSL 1, you *must not* modify the WSL filesystem tree from Windows.

You can access these files from your Ubuntu WSL terminal. To delete the file, use the following command:

```
rm ~/.opam/config
```

If you want to access the filesystem using Windows Explorer, you can use the following syntax:

```
\\wsl$
```

Only WSL instances that are currently running will appear. If the one you want doesn’t appear, launch it from Start Menu and refresh the Explorer view (eg. using <kbd>F5</kbd>).

Comment: This solved the error, thank you so much. One last question: does the ~ in the path just mean the current working directory?

Comment: No, it refers to your home folder, for example `/home/daniel`.